# Получить список доступных дистрибутивов WSL

Tags: windows, powershell, wsl, wsl2

Пытаюсь получить список доступных для установки дистрибутивов WSL:

```
$list_all = @(); $i = 0; wsl.exe --list --online | %{ if(($_.Trim() -ne "") -and ($i -gt 8)){ $list_all += $_.Split(" ") }; $i++ }
```

Если просто вывести `list_all` в консоль, то все будет нормально:

```
PS C:\Users\User> $list_all
Ubuntu
Debian
kali-linux
openSUSE-42
SLES-12
Ubuntu-16.04
Ubuntu-18.04
Ubuntu-20.04
```

Но если попытаться записать его в файл, возникает следующее:

`` Set-Content -Path wsl_list.txt -Value ($list_all -join "`r`n") ``

В файл записывается этот текст:

```
 U b u n t u 
 D e b i a n 
 k a l i - l i n u x 
 o p e n S U S E - 4 2 
 S L E S - 1 2 
 U b u n t u - 1 6 . 0 4 
 U b u n t u - 1 8 . 0 4 
 U b u n t u - 2 0 . 0 4
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего, утилита wsl.exe выводит сведения  в кодировке Unicode. Поэтому рекомендую задать кодировку перед чтением данных: **[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding**. А при записи в файл, вместо дефолтной *utf8NoBOM* использовать *unicode* - нужно к командлету **Set-Content** добавить параметр  **-Encoding unicode**

Answer (score 0):

Получаем список доступных дистрибутивов и их элиаса, выровняя список в консоли с нормальной кодировкой

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

$wsl = wsl --list --online
# We need to get the string number where the "FRIENDLY NAME" header begins to truncate all other unnecessary strings in the beginning
$LineNumber = ($wsl | Select-String -Pattern "FRIENDLY NAME" -CaseSensitive).LineNumber
# Remove first strings in output from the first to the $LineNumber
$Distros = ($wsl).Replace("  ", "").Replace("* ", "")[($LineNumber)..(($wsl).Count)] | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Distro" = ($_ -split " ", 2 | Select-Object -Last 1).Trim()
        "Alias"  = ($_ -split " ", 2 | Select-Object -First 1).Trim()
    }
}
$Distros
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]